# Deserialize self referencing objects with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, circular-dependency, self-reference

I have a JSON string looking like that (simplified):

```js
[
  { "id":1, "friends":[2] },
  { "id":2, "friends":[1,3] },
  { "id":3, "friends":[] }
]
```

The content of friends are ids of other users in the list.

Is it possible somehow to create a Java class like the one below from the JSON just with Data Binding using Jackson or do I need an intermediate step for that?

```java
public class User {
  private long userid;
  private List<User> friends;
// ... getters/setters
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have a similar issue, except where the ID is the key rather than a property and I am referencing it from a completely separate object but in the same document. For example : {"best_friend": "Alice", "friends: {"John": { ... }, "Alice": { ... }, "Soren": { ... }}} which should be parsed to a class with a field "User bestFriend" and a field "Map<String, Object> friends". Since it's been 12 years, I'm hoping there's now a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no fully annotative way to do this, so you would need custom JsonSerializer / JsonDeserializer. Jackson 1.9 adds [two new features](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/10/entry_463.html) that might help:

- ValueInstantiators, so you can add constructors for deserializer to convert from basic integer into POJO
- Value injection so you could pass additional context object (which you would need to find ids of already deserializer objects, to map then from integer to instance)

However I am not 100% sure how to combine these two features for specific use case...